# Does this mail mean that I've been granted the UK Visa?

Tags: visas

What does the below e-mail mean?

This is an email to confirm that your UK visa application has been approved and will now be returned to the Visa Application Centre if you applied through Amman, Cairo or Beirut.

Please allow the following transit times: 
Amman, Cairo, Beirut: 2 days 
Erbil,  Baghdad, Basra: 5 working days
Jerusalem: 5 working days.

You will be contacted by the Visa Application Centre - by e-mail - when your passport and documents are ready for collection. Please do not go to the Visa Application Centre before they have contacted you.

If you have not been contacted, please attend the application centre after the proposed transit times as stated above.

PLEASE DO NOT CALL THE LOCAL BRITISH EMBASSY OR CONSULATE GENERAL AS THIS IS A DIRECT DESPATCH FROM THE UKVI OFFICE IN AMMAN.

- If applied from Iraq: Your decision will be despatched and returned to you by Aramex courier.
- If you have applied from Jerusalem: your decision will be returned to you by Aramex courier.
- If applied from Ramallah: Please note that there is a 2-3 days courier transit period from Amman to The OPTs. You can collect your decision on the next Wednesday allowing for the 2-3 days courier transit period. If you have elected to receive your decision via Aramex, please allow for 3 days and contact your local Aramex office. They should also contact you to advise you to collect your decision. Please note- as advised that there is a fee of 50 NIS on collection by Aramex and this has to be pre-arranged.

You are reminded that you should avoid making travel plans until you have collected your passport.

Please note that only your original documents will be returned. All translations, copies and letters addressed to UKVI will be retained for our records.

If you need to contact us you can do so via our International Enquiry Service at www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-outside-uk

Kind regards,

Regards
UK Visas and Immigration 
British Embassy
Amman
www.gov.uk/ukvi

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have copied the wording correctly? The wording looks very like the standard letter telling you processing the application has been completed, but the word "approved" is not usually in those.

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer your question please advise in a comment to this question and explain why.  We can reopen this question if it is appropriate.

Comment: @DJClayworth yes 100% sure